# Is it possible to obtain status line strings?

Tags: neovim

I am developing a neovim client using RPC, and trying to get all status line texts shown in below figure. Are there any ways to get them?

I have already tried using `execute` function and the redirection function, but they can only get them partially. I would like to get all strings.

[image]

Comment: that are not the statusline strings. You can capture the output from various commands using `redir` or `execute()`, but you cannot obtain the statusline strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `:h :redir`

Try the following:

```
:redir @a
:ls
:redir END
:reg a
```

The above commands will redirect the output of the commands used in between `redir@a` and `redir END` to `register a` (see `:h :reg`).

You can also redirect output to

- A file with `:redir >> file`
- A register with `:redir @{a-z}` or `:redir @{a-z}>`
- Selection clipboard with `:redir @*>`
- A variable with `:redir => {var}`

And you can append (not overwrite) to the already contents stored in the registers, files, variables by using `>>` instead of `>` in all the above `:h :redir` commands. That is you can append the output of a command to

- A file with `:redir >> file`
- A register with `:redir @{a-z}>>` or `:redir @{A-Z}>` or `:redir @{A-Z}`
- Selection clipboard with `:redir @*>>`
- A variable with `:redir =>> {var}`

Comment: Also the `execute()` function returns output